# Raw C++11 strings in macro on VS2013

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, visual-studio-2013, compiler-bug

It seems there is a bug in Visual Studio 2013 compiler concerning the support of C++11 raw strings.

The new raw strings in C++11 look for example like `R"(\s(\d+))"`; they are very handy for regular expressions and multi-line strings. Visual Studio 2013 (and VS 2012 November CTP) supports them, but if you place a raw string inside a macro (even a simple one), bad things can happen.

This simple code compiles but fails on the assertion:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define M(s) s

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* s1 = M(R"()\s)");
    const char* s2 =   R"()\s)";
    assert(strcmp(s1, s2) == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- The macro is as simple as it can be.
- If inside the string the right parenthesis is removed, everything works.
- If inside the string the backslash or the `'s'` letter is removed, the code doesn't compile!

Is it really a compiler bug ? If yes, is it a known bug ? Are there workarounds ?

Comment: It looks like [this bug, What's special about R and L in the C++ preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098486/whats-special-about-r-and-l-in-the-c-preprocessor) it will be fixed with the next release and there are no real work-arounds.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is the same bug, there is a bug report linked in the dup at the top of my answer.

Comment: Maybe, but I think it is a different bug. Notably because it also happens with `L` prefix, which is a completely other and older thing, and has something to do with the `#` operator, not with a right parenthesis. Anyway, the MSVC preprocessor seems quite buggy.

Comment: You can open up a new bug report and mention it looks similar but you don't think it is the same bug. If it is the same they will close as  a dup and let you know. Since they don't explain the root cause it is hard to know but my testing indicates the two bugs have similar behavior.